# How to fill column using values in 2 other columns in PROC SQL / SAS code in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide, 4gl

I have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

Data types:

- VAL1 - character
- ID - numeric
- VAL2 - character (with only 3 possible values: P, C, S)

  | ID | EVENT | GRADE |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 123 | NY | P |
  | 123 | NY | P |
  | 123 | NY | S |
  | 55 | MAD | C |
  | 55 | MAD | S |
  | 55 | LON | S |
- ID - column with ID
- EVENT - event name
- GRADE - evaluation of the event (mark)

And I need to create table where will be ID, EVENT and GRADE of event, but:

- grade P or C are more important that grade S, so if some pair ID - EVENT has P or C then this pair ID - EVENT has P or C
- when some pair ID-EVENT has only grade S (without P or C) then stay S

So as a result I need something like below:

```
ID  |EVENT|GRADE
----|-----|----
123 | NY  | P  --> because P is more important than S
55  | MAD | C  --> because C is more important than S
55  | LON | S  --> because has only S
```

How can I do that in normal SAS code or in PROC SQL in Enterprise Guide ? :)

Comment: Instead of posting a duplicate question (and just changing the variable names) you should update your original question.

Comment: You are right, but i am new here, I did not know that - I think that now this question is more clearly, do you have some idea ? :)

Comment: I would delete this duplicate if I were you, as you don't really want to irk mods. You can edit the original question with more details. But it was more or less clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SQL-based solution that will work assuming `C` and `P` only occur once per id & event. We'll assign values to `C`, `P`, and `S`:

```
C, P = 1
S    = 2
```

If we take the minimum of those values per `(id, event)`, we will be left with a unique list of IDs and events in a hierarchical order.

```
proc sql;
    create table want(drop=value) as
        select distinct 
            id
          , event
          , grade
          , CASE when grade IN('C', 'P') then 1 else 2 END as value
        from have
        group by id, event
        having value = min(value)
    ;
quit;
```